# Vector iterators don't work as expected (THREAD 1 BAD_EXEC error)

Tags: c++

I don't understand why these two loop don't give identical results. Uncommented loop gives correct result only for vectors that have multiple of 3 elements (i.e 3,6,9 etc), while the commented loop works for any size vector.

```
//Find max product of two adjacent elements in vector

int adjacentElementsProduct(std::vector<int> inputArray) {
int maxProduct=0;
for (auto it=inputArray.begin(); it!=inputArray.end(); ++it) {
    if ((*it * *++it)>maxProduct)
        maxProduct = *it * *++it;
}
//    for (int i=0; i<inputArray.size(); ++i) {
//        if ((inputArrcay[i] * inputArray[i+1])>maxProduct) 
//             maxProduct = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1];
//            
//        
//     }
      return maxProduct;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your loops have a past-the-end read, which is pretty serious bug.
But with iterator loop, you have another bug which changes the results:

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(std::vector<int> inputArray) {
  int maxProduct=0;
  for (auto it=inputArray.begin(); it!=inputArray.end(); ++it) { // INCREMENT
    if ((*it * *++it)>maxProduct) // INCREMENT
        maxProduct = *it * *++it; // INCREMENT
  }
  return maxProduct;
}
```

++it actually increments the iterator.  Therefore you are incrementing the iterator in several places, and can jump past the end (and if that happens it'll keep reading until something really bad happens, as it is undefined behavior.)  Even if you don't jump past the end, you still end up skipping over values, and that's likely why you're seeing different results.  You should use it+1 instead of ++it, since it doesn't have the side effect of advancing the iterator.  In the worst case, a single iteration of your loop will increment the iterator THREE times.

When you dereference it+1, though, you still might be dereferencing the end iterator.  Therefore you should change your logic a bit.  Also, pass the vector by reference to avoid doing a potentially expensive copy:

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(std::vector<int> const & inputArray) {
  int maxProduct = 0;
  if (inputArray.size() > 1) {
    for (auto it = ++inputArray.begin(); it != inputArray.end(); ++it) {
      int prod = *it * *(it-1);
      if (prod > maxProduct) {
         maxProduct = prod;
      }
    }
  }
  return maxProduct;
}
```

I prefer using an index variable for cleanliness and simplicity though.  Note, I pre-advanced the iterator and then did the product of the current item and the previous, rather than the current and the next.  That's why I pre-checked that there's more than 1 item in the vector.

Comment: Try that on this input: `std::vector<int> v { 1, -2, 3, -4, 1, -7 };` The correct result is `-2`.  The function will return 0.

Comment: I was considering changing the initializer to min negative int, but too many changes start to answer a question other than what the OP asked.  But both of these are good points.  It can overflow and it can be wrong with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

DANG you're quick with the green check mark. Doing that can discourage answers.

Anyway ... What they said. ... Faulty logic and indexing out of bounds.

Things to note: I am posting a complete program, all in one piece, that can be compiled and run, as is. This is called  Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, and it is *de rigueur* for StackOverflow questions. Do that in your questions from now on. I passed the vector by const reference. I changed the type from int to unsigned, because that was apparently your intent. *What if the values alternate positive and negative? Bug, that's what.* I checked for the edge-case in which there were no pairs of adjacent values to multiply. Throwing an exception is better than returning a number that is not actually the product of two adjacent values, as advertised. I used std::max to compute the maximum product.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

unsigned adjacentElementsProduct(const std::vector<unsigned> &inputArray) {    
    if (inputArray.size() < 2)
        { throw std::range_error("adjacentElementsProduct vector.size() < 2"); }
    unsigned maxProduct= 0u;
    for (auto it=inputArray.begin(); it!=inputArray.end()-1; ++it) {
        maxProduct = std::max(maxProduct,  it[0] * it[1]);
    }
    return maxProduct;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned> v{ 1,4,0,37,5,2,2,37 };
    std::cout << adjacentElementsProduct(v) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing the type to `unsigned` is a bad idea. The algorithm should generally work for signed types.

Comment: @FelixDombek - Well, I'm not a mind reader, but the fact that the OP thought 0 was the smallest possible answer made me think he was considering only positive numbers. He seems to have disappeared anyway. He gave the greeny to an answer that has a couple of bugs, and then vamoosed.

Comment: Thanks @JiveDadson! Your code is definitely better than then one I accepted, but I would leave my green mark on that because that answer actually answers my question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone! My final version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int adjacentElementsProduct(std::vector<int> &inputArray) {
    int maxProduct=-1000; //Elements of vector cannot be <-1000
    if (inputArray.size() >1) {
        for (auto it=++inputArray.begin(); it!=inputArray.end(); ++it) {
            int p = (*it) * (*(it-1));
            if (p>maxProduct)
                maxProduct = p;
        }
    }
    return maxProduct;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> v { 1, -2, 3, -4, 1, -7 };
    std::cout << adjacentElementsProduct(v) << std::endl;
}
```